# how to make active only one radio button for all the sections?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

here i had divided into sections in it each section there are rows depending on count so for every row the radio button will be there and i need to make active only one radio button for all of the sections but i am unable to implement it and the image for sections will be shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3euM.png) and my code is

```
@IBAction func paymentRadioAction(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
        let chekIndex = self.checkIsPaymentRadioSelect.index(of: sender.tag)
        if sender.isSelected {

        } else{
            if(chekIndex == nil){
                self.checkIsPaymentRadioSelect.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                self.checkIsPaymentRadioSelect.append(sender.tag)
                self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

here is the code for cell for row at indexpath

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! shippingMethodTableViewCell
            var key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
            print(key)
            var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
            var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
            let name = dictionary["name"]
            let price = dictionary ["price"]
            cell.methodNameLabel.text = name  as! String
            cell.priceLabel.text = price as! String
            let checkIndex = self.checkIsPaymentRadioSelect.index(of: indexPath.row)
            if(checkIndex != nil){
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
            }else{
                cell.radioButton.isSelected = false
            }
            return cell
        }
```

Comment: Could you please specify what is the use of `checkIsPaymentRadioSelect` array?

Comment: that is for bool to know which row@AravindAR

Comment: Whether it is to know which radioButton is tapped ??

Comment: yes for which button selection @AravindAR

Comment: At a time only one among all the radioButton needs to be selected right?
If I select 2nd one first and then 5th one only the 5th gets selected and 2nd will be deselected right ?

Comment: yes only one radio needs to be active @AravindAR

Comment: One more thing is the radioButton simply a UIButton ?

Comment: no i had used kgradio button @AravindAR

Comment: i forgot to say that in the image flat and united parcel service are sections inside it rows are there in that radio buttons are there @AravindAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you don't have to use an array to keep track of the selected radio button

Make `chekIndex` as global variable of type `IndexPath` as `var chekIndex:IndexPath?`
and modify the code as below

```
   @IBAction func paymentRadioAction(_ sender: KGRadioButton) {
     let center = sender.center;
    let centralPOint = sender.superview?.convert(sender.center, to:self.shippingTableView )
    let indexPath =  self.shippingTableView.indexPathForRow(at: centralPoint)

    if sender.isSelected {

    } else{
        chekIndex = indexPath
        self.shippingTableView.reloadData()
    }
}


let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "shippingCell", for: indexPath) as! shippingMethodTableViewCell
var key = self.keys[indexPath.section]
print(key)
var a :[Any]  = arrayss[key] as! [Any]
var dictionary = a[indexPath.row] as! [String:Any]
let name = dictionary["name"]
let price = dictionary ["price"]
cell.methodNameLabel.text = name  as! String
cell.priceLabel.text = price as! String
if checkIndex == indexPath {
    cell.radioButton.isSelected = true
} else {
    cell.radioButton.isSelected = false

}
return cell
}
```

Comment: Could you please put the code of how you have declared checkIndex ?

Comment: var chekIndex: [Int] = [] this i had declared

Comment: but later i changed to . what u said then also it was displaying wrongly as shown in image https://i.stack.imgur.com/tF371.png

Comment: both radio buttons are getting selected is that the issue ?

Comment: yes when i select first in first section but it is enabling first in second section also

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you were using sections.

Comment: bro do you have any idea of giving table view height constraints dynamically ?

Comment: You can use UItableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: i am using two table views on a common scroll so i need to make dynamical height increment do you have any idea

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't completely get your question

Comment: i am using two table views on a scrollview of back side for both

Comment: on first table view i am having radio buttons if i enable then i need to show the below table if not i need not to display

Comment: You can hide or show the table on the IBAction I guess.

Comment: no i am asking if the data on first table got increased or decreased then how to make constraints dynamically to fit the scroll view

Comment: you can change the scrollView's content height based on content height of tableview I believe

Comment: that' s only how i am asking ?

Comment: r u having any idea  ?